# Center the DIV in DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello i have a next html code and CSS:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.teaser {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25vh;
  background-image: url("http://www.1zoom.me/big2/365/321125-alexfas01.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
a.menuButton {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 49.7%;
  height: 33.33%;
  float: left;
  background-color: white;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #E6F0F0;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  color: black;
}
.rectangle {
  padding: 0;
  width: 70px;
  height: 7px;
  background: blue;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.menuButtonContent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  margin: auto;
}
.menuButtonContent h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
.buttonsWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 73vh;
}
.rectangle#citizenship {
  background-color: #38CCBA;
}
.rectangle#fastsearch {
  background-color: #00899B;
}
.rectangle#forillegals {
  background-color: #D80C00;
}
.rectangle#soonillegals {
  background-color: #FF8A00;
}
.rectangle#aboutapp {
  background-color: #B8B8B8;
}
.rectangle#settings {
  background-color: #626262;
}
```

```html
<div class="teaser"></div>
<div class="buttonsWrapper">
  <a class="menuButton" href="#">
    <div class="menuButtonContent">
      <h1>Citizenship</h1>
      <div class="rectangle" id="citizenship"></div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="menuButton" href="#">
    <div class="menuButtonContent">
      <h1>Fast search</h1>
      <div class="rectangle" id="fastsearch"></div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="menuButton" href="#">
    <div class="menuButtonContent">
      <h1>For illegals</h1>
      <div class="rectangle" id="forillegals"></div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="menuButton" href="#">
    <div class="menuButtonContent">
      <h1>Soon illegals</h1>
      <div class="rectangle" id="soonillegals"></div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="menuButton" href="#">
    <div class="menuButtonContent">
      <h1>About app</h1>
      <div class="rectangle" id="aboutapp"></div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="menuButton" href="#">
    <div class="menuButtonContent">
      <h1>Settings</h1>
      <div class="rectangle" id="settings"></div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

I have 2 problems:

1) I cannot find an apropriate solution to center the .menuButtonContent, it is centered horizontaly, but not vertically, on some screen sizes it gets centered vertically, but not at all - how can i center it?

2) The background-image: url doesn't get rendered, why?

Comment: Your browser would have shown you the answer to your second question – if you have had looked at the console output: »Mixed Content: The page at 'https://stacksnippets.net/js' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.1zoom.me/big2/365/321125-alexfas01.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.«

Comment: See there http://howtocenterincss.com/

Comment: Your image link isn't a valid link to an image...

Comment: This is the real link: http://s1.1zoom.me/big0/365/321125-alexfas01.jpg

Comment: From the top of a Google search for “css vertically center”: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/, http://davidwalsh.name/css-vertical-center, https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: @Nelson Teixeira now only Chrome renders the image, but its a progress =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make an element vertically align centered, set the display property of the parent element as `display:table;` then set the element that has to be centered  as `display:table-cell;` and `vertical-align:midlle;`.

```
.parent{
    display:table;
}

.child-element-centered{
   display:table-cell;
   vertical-align:midlle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `calc()` function in CSS

lets say the parent div is called "a" and its child was "b"

```
<div id="a" style="width:400px;height:400px;position:relative;">
     <div id="b" style="position:relative;top:calc(25% - 100px);left:calc(25% - 100px);width:50%;height:50%;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: PSA: `calc()` is an experimental technology ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)) that still requires the use of vendor prefixes from some browsers and is not implemented with all of them yet.

Comment: The CSS in the question does not contain any absolute pixel values and `calc` still has flaws in some browsers when using percentages. See also: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Comment: I think there is Only lower versions of internet explorer and opera that isnt compatible

Comment: @JohnHudson IE9-10-11, Edge, Safari, iOS Safari and Firefox have known issues regarding `calc()`  http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc (Known issues tab)

Comment: I Use Firefox and Occasionally Safari on My friends Tablet and have no problems with it, Microsoft Edge yes you will have to put measures in place as fallback content and IOS Safari works because of it having a HTML Application Interface

Comment: @JohnHudson That is a perfectly valid reason not to use this. Most of my customers still have large user bases with an IE 9.

Comment: there is fallback content basic javascript will do what you want

Answer (score 0):

first set the `display` of child divs to `inline-block`

then set the parent `text-align` to `center`. This will horizontally center your divs

and then use a "hack" to accomplish vertically aligning your child divs. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7qpvdbqs/3/) for an example